# { or ; expected error

Tags: c#

Code:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Button OpenBtn;


private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panelMain;
private DCMViewer myView = new DCMViewer();
private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox DCMListView;
private System.Windows.Forms.Button DCMOpenBtn;
private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView1;
private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader TagName;
private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader VRValue;
private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader TagValue;

public DCMViewer MyView { get **=>** myView; set => myView = value; }
```

The `**=>**` symbol produces this error:

```
{ or ; expected
```

Comment: That's C#7 syntax. You have to be able to use it, are you?

Comment: Although it would be simpler just not to have the field declared in source code at all, and use an automatically implemented property: `public DOMViewer MyView { get; set; }`

Comment: Just to be clear, you used `**` to denote which part of the code that gives an error, those asterixes aren't *actually* part of your code?

Comment: Does your code literally contain `**=>**`, or were you trying to bold the `=>` symbol?

Comment: @halfer That made me laugh.

Comment: @davisj1691: heh, though some folks really do try to add formatting in code blocks (and then don't realise how much it confuses the question :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close, since the presentation of the question is wasting a significant amount of helper time, and we'd need to see the structure of the class to see if there is a brace problem, and if so, where that issue is. 노시형, please improve this question promptly, thank you (we need an [mcve]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though you have some illegal characters in the body of your expression for `MyView`:

**Change:**

```
public DCMViewer MyView { get **=>** myView; set => myView = value; }
```

**To:**

```
public DCMViewer MyView { get => myView; set => myView = value;
```

I did a test on the syntax and received the same error while trying to follow the traditional [expression body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#property-get-statements), your issue could just be that you're not all the way to C# 6 syntax (which I don't understand since I can use expression bodied methods but not the `get` accessor). I would recommend automatically implemented properties as below, or go with a more traditional approach if you prefer. Personally, you really have no need to declare bodies for `get` and `set` since you aren't doing anything special with the underlying fields. Thus you can just use an automatically implemented property:

```
public DCMViewer MyView { get; set; }
```

Comment: Isn't that the one on the next line?

Comment: Ah, it looks like my edit dropped the closing brace to the next line. Such is the consequences of presenting an unformatted post! I will repair.

Comment: No, the one on the next line is ending the class (or so it seems, the tabbing is different than the compiler would place it for sure).

Answer (score 0):

internal static Cell Food

get *>** food; set => food = Value; }

set=> FoodCount= Value;

public static int FoodCount1 { get = FoodCount; {or; expected